# How can I maintain the type invariant of a Range type where the lower bound is always less than or equal to the upper bound

Tags: haskell

I am trying to model a generic `Range` type with the following definition:

```hs
data Range a = Range
  { lower :: a
  , upper :: a }
```

I added a smart constructor (and only exported it without the data constructor) so that consumers cannot accidentally create a `Range` with its `lower` field larger than its `upper` field:

```hs
range :: Ord a => a -> a -> Range a
range lower upper =
  if lower > upper
  then Range upper lower
  else Range lower upper
```

This is all good and I moved on with deriving a `Functor` instance of it:

```hs
instance Functor Range where
  fmap f (Range lower upper) = Range (f lower) (f upper)
```

This became problematic because I can do:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let r1 = range 1 2
      r2 = fmap negate r1
  return ()
  -- Now r2 has its upper field less than its lower field
```

My naive attempt would be to use the smart constructor `range` in the implementation of `fmap` like:

```hs
instance Functor Range where
  fmap f (Range lower upper) = range (f lower) (f upper)
```

However, this does not compile as `f lower` and `f upper` are not constrained to have an `Ord a` instance.

How can I fix this so I can maintain the type invariant of having `lower` always less than or equal to `upper`?

Comment: There's no way to make this a legal functor while maintaining the invariant, because you'd need to be able to represent values of type `Range a` for which there is no `Ord` instance, and the concept of "the smaller value" isn't defined. Have you considered defining `rangeMap :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> Range a -> Range b`, (this is how [set](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.6/docs/Data-Set.html#v:map) does it)

Comment: Your type is not a functor "in Hask", where by "in Hask" I mean that `fmap f` will work for _any_ Haskell-definable function `f`. That's false since `f` does not have to be monotonic. (Also, you need the target type to be ordered.) At best, you can define a custom functor class which allows you to restrict `f` to monotonic functions as well. Still, this will be a distinct class from `Functor`. Perhaps in the libraries there already is such a custom "restricted functor" class -- I have no idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there's no way to make this a legal functor, because `fmap f` has to work for all functions `f`, even when the result type doesn't have an `Ord` instance.

As I see it, you have two good options:

---

First: don't define a functor constraint, make a new function `rangeMap` with a more restricted type (this is how [set](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.6/docs/Data-Set.html#v:map) does it).

```hs
data Range a = Range { lower :: a, higher :: a } deriving Show

range :: Ord a => a -> a -> Range a
range lower upper =
  if lower > upper
  then Range upper lower
  else Range lower upper

rangeMap :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> Range a -> Range b
rangeMap f (Range x1 x2) = range (f x1) (f x2)
```

```hs
rangeMap (negate) $ range 2 1 
Range {lower = -2, higher = -1}
```

---

Second, change the representation of range so that it does support a `Functor` instance, but implement `lower` and `higher` as functions that require an `Ord` constraint.

```hs
data Range a = Range a a

instance Functor Range where
  fmap f (Range x1 x2) = Range (f x1) (f x2)

lower :: Ord a => Range a -> a
lower (Range x1 x2) = min x1 x2

higher :: Ord a => Range a -> a
higher (Range x1 x2) = max x1 x2
```

```hs
λ:r = negate <$> Range 1 2
λ:lower r
-2
λ:higher r
-1
```

---

Depending on your usecase, either one of these two approaches might be preferable.

Comment: if you derive `Functor` and `Traversable` for the second type of `Range` definition then you should be able to define `lower` and `higher` as `lower = minimum` `higher = maximum`

Comment: I think deriving `Traversable` (or implementing it by any other means) would break an important abstraction boundary. It lets you observe the difference between `Range lo hi` and `Range hi lo` even though semantically they are intended to be identical under approach 2.

Comment: Oh, it's probably also worth pointing out that if you were to derive it, the stock `Eq` instance for the second `Range` defintion wouldn't do what you want. Although you should be able to write an `instance Ord a => Eq (Range a)` (I think that's legal)

Comment: Thanks! Both are very valid solutions!

Comment: @Joe Right. But actually `instance Eq a => Eq (Range a)` is possible and probably not even less efficient! `Range lo hi == Range lo' hi' = (lo == lo' && hi == hi') || (lo == hi' && hi == lo')`

Comment: Wow, second solution is incredibly clever! Can I use it